# Problem for leg_detector in People package when using rosbag play

Tags: ros, rosbag, leg-detector, people

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have collected /tf and /scan data from a Turtlebot2( i.e. Kobuki robot) by using rosbag record. I also have written a new tracker and want to test it  with the recorded data beforehand.  The new tracker was based on the leg_detector package.  The main modification is the member variable " filter_"  in class SavedFeature was changed to be the new tracker.
With the record data, it is possible to compare the tracking results of my tracker with the one in people package.
The launch file is displayed below:

```
<launch>
  <node name="laser_filter" pkg="laser_filters" type="scan_to_scan_filter_chain" respawn="true">
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find people_tracking_filter)/config/filters.yaml"/>
  </node>
  <node pkg="leg_detector" type="leg_detector" name="leg_detector" args="scan:=base_scan $(find leg_detector)/config/trained_leg_detector.yaml" output="screen">
   <remap from ="scan" to ="scan_filtered"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

The laser_filter node works fine with the being played bagfile data,  the scan_filtered topic ouput normally. However, the leg_detector doesn't work. No messages output in topic /leg_tracker_measuremens.
An warning messages came out:

```
[ WARN] [1422844504.014663321, 1422676497.431818087]: MessageFilter [target=odom_combined ]: Dropped 100.00% of messages so far. Please turn the [ros.leg_detector.message_notifier] rosconsole logger to DEBUG for more information.
```

This warning is quite strange. Because I have changed all "odom_combined" to be "odom" and it works in the real robot test as I said in [this previous tips](http://answers.ros.org/question/200158/problem-with-leg_detector-in-people-dropped-10000-message-so-far/)

Looking forwards to any advices. Especially to the author and maintainer @David lu

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202208/problem-for-leg_detector-in-people-package-when-using-rosbag-play/) by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 279 on 2015-02-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you setting the /use_sim_time parameter to true?

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2015-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0